# Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error '

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I am trying to use TikzEdt tool to generate some graphs....It was working very nicelly, until I tried the `extended mode`, and from that instance, it is reporting an error.
Here is the preamble

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% needed for BB
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   
%% Begin Added by me
\usepackage{pdfpages}       %To be able to insert PDF pages   
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
%% End of added by me
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

and here is a very basic code

```
% Define block styles    
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']  

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm,auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [draw,rounded corners] (node1) {node1};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried `(Re-)Generate Precompiled headers`   and this is what I get:

```
Generating precompiled header: pdflatex -ini -jobname="temp_header" "&pdflatex temp_header.tex\dump"
Compilation of pre-compiled header failed with exit code 1. Compilation of main document stopped. Check that all necessary packages are installed and that the pre-compiled header code (in the settings) has no errors!
```

A file named `temp_header.auxlock` is generated containing one single line  `\def \tikzexternallocked {0}`
Can any one please suggest some help?

Comment: And how did you try to enter `extended mode` in `tikzedt`?. I think you are trying to overuse `tikzedt`. It is meant primarily to draw `tikz` pictures and not for writing articles. Please try some other LaTeX editors.

Comment: Your additions work fine for me. However you can try with `(Re-)Generate precompiled headers` in `Compilation` menu.

Comment: @HarishKumar, I am not using it for documents, but only for graphs....The regeneration also gave an error (see thread update)...As for your question, with a given document, the number of points exceeded the limit, so, I've read somewhere that one has to enter the extended mode. Didn't work, so I had to reduce the number of points..but now, nothing is working.

Comment: Instead of trying to modify the precompiled header, you can use `standalone option of `tikzedt`. In the side bar,look for `standalone` and in that `standalone document`.

Comment: @HarishKumar can you please include a snapshot? my TikzEdt seems not to have the standalone version...

Comment: Version 0.2.3.0 has it. Which is your version? See the screen shot.

Comment: The standalone version is working just fine. Which means there is a problem in my Preamble in the settings or **Precompilation argument** `-ini -jobname="$JOBNAME$" "&pdflatex $FILENAME$\dump" `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution with the help of a  friend. in the directory ...`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\TikzEdt\TikzEdt\0.2.3.0` open the file `temp_header.tex` and make sure it maches the Pre-amble in TikzEdt. The directory and the file are both hidden, so you have to check that hidden files are displayed.

Comment: I didn't have your problem but looking at the file `temp_header.tex` I solved mine too. 
  

I've also found some other useful files: `TE_temp_previewNNNNN.tex`, `.log`, etc. (where NNNNN is the current process number) in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp`.